Gracefully Closing a TCP Connection from Client Side in Go while Ensuring All Data is Read and Responded
I'm implementing a TCP client and server in Go. The communication pattern is as follows:
TCP Server:

Writes data to the TCP client.
Reads responses from the TCP client.

TCP Client:

Reads data from the TCP server.
Writes responses back to the TCP server.

At some point, I want the TCP client to initiate the closure of the connection. When doing so, I need to achieve the following:

Stop the TCP server from writing any new data to the connection.
Ensure the TCP client reads all data that has already been written to the connection.
After reading, the TCP client should send responses back to the TCP server for the data it has read.
Once all of the above is completed, the TCP connection should be closed gracefully.

I want to make sure that no data is lost during this shutdown process and that both the client and server handle the closure properly.
I'm aware that I can implement an application-level shutdown signal (e.g., sending a "SHUTDOWN" message) from the client to the server to notify it to stop sending data. However, I'm curious if there's a way to achieve this using TCP connection methods (CloseWrite(), CloseRead(), or others) in Go.
I want to avoid abrupt termination of the connection and ensure that both the client and server handle the closure gracefully.

Go doesn't change the semantics of the TCP connection, it works the same under any language. What makes you think that data will be lost if you've already sent the data?

If you're asking whether you can ask the server to stop writing from the client with TCP alone, no you cannot. The client can shutdown read (CloseRead in Go), but the server won't know until it has sent data and received an error.

If you want the client to read and respond to all messages sent by the server, then only option is to use an application-level shutdown signal.  If the client tries to initiate shutdown with CloseWrite, then the client cannot respond to messages received after the call to CloseWrite.  If the client tries to initiate shutdown with CloseRead, then the server does not detect shutdown until after the server attempts to send a message.

Thank you for the explanations.
I just wanted to know if there are any other ways to stop the server from writing besides an application-level shutdown.
I'll try to use an application-level shutdown.

@kin TCP has a notion of "out of band" data.  You can use that as your application-level shutdown signal, if you don't want to send an actual message inside of your normal protocol stream. The server can monitor for both OOB and Stream data at the same time, and then act according to which one it receives.

When operating with TCP connections, it is tempting to use the net.Conn interface. However, the Close() method for this interface terminates both directions of the connection. If you deal with the underlying implementation (*net.TCPConn), you get access to more functionality.
If I understand what you are asking, you want that extra functionality to perform operations like this:
// Program trythis
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var (
    dest       = flag.String("dest", "localhost:2000", "address to talk with")
    serveLoop  = flag.Int("serves", 2, "number of served requests")
    clientLoop = flag.Int("clients", 3, "number of client requests")
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func client() {
    defer wg.Done()
    var tcp *net.TCPConn
    for tcp == nil {
        c, err := net.Dial("tcp", *dest)
        if err != nil {
            time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
            continue
        }
        var ok bool
        tcp, ok = c.(*net.TCPConn)
        if !ok {
            log.Fatalf("tcp connection not a TCP connection: %v", err)
        }
        defer tcp.CloseRead()
    }
    answer := make([]byte, 100)
    for i := 0; i < *clientLoop; i++ {
        n, err := tcp.Read(answer)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("client read failed: %v", err)
            break
        }
        got := string(answer[:n-1])
        send := fmt.Sprintf("client message#%d\n", i)
        log.Printf("client got %q .. sending %q", got, send)
        n, err = fmt.Fprint(tcp, send)
        if n != len(send) || err != nil {
            log.Printf("server issue writing: %d, %v", n, err)
            break
        }
    }
    tcp.CloseWrite()
    log.Printf("client exiting")
}

func server() {
    defer wg.Done()
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", *dest)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("unable to listen to %q: %v", *dest, err)
    }
    defer lis.Close()
    var tcp *net.TCPConn
    for tcp == nil {
        c, err := lis.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("accept failed for %q: %v", *dest, err)
        }
        var ok bool
        tcp, ok = c.(*net.TCPConn)
        if !ok {
            log.Fatalf("tcp connection not a TCP connection: %v", err)
        }
        defer tcp.CloseWrite()
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(tcp, "hi\n")
    request := make([]byte, 100)
    for i := 0; i < *serveLoop; i++ {
        n, err := tcp.Read(request)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("server got error reading: %v", err)
            break
        }
        got := string(request[:n])
        log.Printf("server got=%q", got)
        send := fmt.Sprintf("server acknowledges [%d]: %q\n", i, got)
        n, err = fmt.Fprint(tcp, send)
        if n != len(send) || err != nil {
            log.Printf("client issue writing: %d, %v", n, err)
            break
        }
    }
    tcp.CloseRead()
    log.Printf("server exiting")
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    wg.Add(2)
    go client()
    go server()
    wg.Wait()
    log.Print("success")
}

Run it (three different cases: client and server agree on expected message exchanges; server expects more of client; client expects more of server) like this:
$ go run trythis.go 
2024/11/30 19:18:16 client got "hi" .. sending "client message#0\n"
2024/11/30 19:18:16 server got="client message#0\n"
2024/11/30 19:18:16 client got "server acknowledges [0]: \"client message#0\\n\"" .. sending "client message#1\n"
2024/11/30 19:18:16 server got="client message#1\n"
2024/11/30 19:18:16 server exiting
2024/11/30 19:18:16 client got "server acknowledges [1]: \"client message#1\\n\"" .. sending "client message#2\n"
2024/11/30 19:18:16 client exiting
2024/11/30 19:18:16 success
$ go run trythis.go --serves=10
2024/11/30 19:20:45 client got "hi" .. sending "client message#0\n"
2024/11/30 19:20:45 server got="client message#0\n"
2024/11/30 19:20:45 client got "server acknowledges [0]: \"client message#0\\n\"" .. sending "client message#1\n"
2024/11/30 19:20:45 server got="client message#1\n"
2024/11/30 19:20:45 client got "server acknowledges [1]: \"client message#1\\n\"" .. sending "client message#2\n"
2024/11/30 19:20:45 client exiting
2024/11/30 19:20:45 server got="client message#2\n"
2024/11/30 19:20:45 server got error reading: EOF
2024/11/30 19:20:45 server exiting
2024/11/30 19:20:45 success
$ go run trythis.go --clients=10
2024/11/30 19:21:04 client got "hi" .. sending "client message#0\n"
2024/11/30 19:21:04 server got="client message#0\n"
2024/11/30 19:21:04 client got "server acknowledges [0]: \"client message#0\\n\"" .. sending "client message#1\n"
2024/11/30 19:21:04 server got="client message#1\n"
2024/11/30 19:21:04 server exiting
2024/11/30 19:21:04 client got "server acknowledges [1]: \"client message#1\\n\"" .. sending "client message#2\n"
2024/11/30 19:21:04 client read failed: EOF
2024/11/30 19:21:04 client exiting
2024/11/30 19:21:04 success

